# Filter dates to only include previous month to today

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI related question.
I am currently using the below measure to filter dates. What I am attempting to do is filter on any dates from the previous month up to todays date. (Note that the formula needs to by dynamic enough so that the year change won't affect it. e.g. we are now in 2022 but I am capturing data from Dec 2019 up until future dates).

```
todaysDate = TODAY()

FilterOnPreviousMonth = 
var filteredResult = IF(DATEDIFF(MAX(Tasks[Target Date]),[todaysDate],MONTH)=1,1,0)
return filteredResult
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Cian

Comment: Add some dummy data andy your desired output;

probably you can use FILTER(ALL('Caledar'[date]), 'Caledar'[date] <= TODAY() && 'Caledar'[date] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1) )

it depends how you want to use the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking. But in any case, one way to handle previous month considerations that are dynamic (that is, that can understand to go back one month *and* account for the year) is to use the `EDATE()` function. You can use this in combination with piping in values to the `DATE()` function. I have provided some example code below to point you in the right direction.

```
EDATE Example = 
VAR _Today = TODAY() -- 1/17/2022
VAR oneMonthBack = EDATE( _Today, -1 ) -- 12/17/2021
VAR lastMonthNumber = MONTH( oneMonthBack ) -- 12
VAR lastMonthYear = YEAR( oneMonthBack ) -- 2021
VAR firstOfLastMonth = DATE( lastMonthYear, lastMonthNumber, 1 ) -- 12/1/2021
RETURN firstOfLastMonth
```